# jenkins index.html test report is not navigatable

Tags: jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I am using publish java doc plugin to publish my testng report, but after switching the jenkins machine, my test results is showing up however I can't navigate thru it
[image]

Comment: why are you using javadoc publish plugin for testng reports?  Wouldn't this help : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin

Comment: I have a custom report page, that i am publishing.